# Strange behaviour of ImageViews of the last item in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. In every row there is an ImageView that is visible only under certain constraints. The problem is that if the first row has this ImageView visible, so it is for the last row as well and viceversa.

Here is the `getView()` code of my adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_idea, null);
    }

    Idea idea = mIdeas.get(position);

    if (idea != null) {
        ImageView imgAlarm = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imgAlarm_rowIdea);
        if (idea.getTimeReminder() != null)
            imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

        TextView lblTitle = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.lblTitle_rowIdea);
        lblTitle.setText(idea.getTitle());

        TextView lblDescription = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.lblDescription_rowIdea);
        lblDescription.setText(idea.getDescription());
    }
    return view;
}
```

`mIdeas` is an `ArrayList` with all the data to display in the `ListView`.
`imgAlarm` is the `ImageView` that I told above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (idea.getTimeReminder() != null)
            imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

to

```
if (idea.getTimeReminder() != null)
            imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
else
            imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
```

What's happening here is that the adapter is "recycling" the views.  So in the case you're seeing in your tests, the last view and the first view are actually the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to revert the visibility status of the `ImageView` if the condition is not met so you don't have problems with a potential recycled view(which could have the `ImageView` already visible and appearing when it shouldn't):

```
if (idea.getTimeReminder() != null) {
     imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
} else {
    imgAlarm.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE); // or GONE
}
```